# export/import js переменных не работает vue-cli

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vue.js, vue-cli

Не работает export/import  js файлов обновил все пакеты даже переустанавливал vue не могу сделать банальный export переменной  [image: vue-cli eslint]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53333105/9435985, если поможет - разместите как ответ на свой вопрос